# Expressão Regular que impossibilita SQL Injection

Tags: regex

Estou procurando alguma maneira de evitar SQL Injection no sistema que estou desenvolvendo.

Existe alguma expressão regular que percebe a tentativa de uma possível tentativa de SQL Injection?

Vocês sabem alguma outra forma de evitá-la? Às vezes pode até existir melhores formas de prevenção mas ainda desconheço.

Comment: Expressão regular pra tratar SQL Injection? Não é melhor usar algum recurso pronto que trate disso usando parâmetros nas _queries_? Aliás, qual a linguagem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *SQL injections* em geral possuem `=`ou `;`, elas basicamente são constituidas em 2 grupos, "*Always true*" ou "*Batched SQL Statements*".

Sugiro que use uma *regex* que capture um desses caracteres citados no `input` e faça um tratamanto ou dê algum erro e não complete a `transaction` para o BD. Como não foi citado o *flavour* da *regex* ou linguagem de desenvolvimento, vou utilizar o flavour mais comum, o utilizado por `php`.

```
(.*?[=|;].*)
```

Explicação:

- `()` delimita o que será capturado
- `.*?` implica que qualquer caractere exceto quebras de linhas serão capturado até chegar a limitação.
- `[=|;]` é a limitação onde o `.*?`, deve parar, implica uma condição para captura, deve ser capturado todos aqueles caracteres apenas se houver `=` OU (`|`) `;`
- `.*` implica que após a captura do carácter obrigatório (`=` ou `;`) capturará todos os caracteres até o fim da linha.

Isso deve ajuda-lo, caso o *flavour* da *regex* for diferente, edite sua pergunta que eu editarei essa *regex* para melhor atende-lo.

Você pode testar a regex que te falei [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/tbUFqt/2)

Comment: Muito obrigado! A linguagem é exatamente PHP. vou utilizar dessa forma